# How to optimize the filter logic below to only use 1 loop instead of 2?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter, logic

JSfiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/bryanh210/j8yz2sep/3/

I currently have this block of code and think the solution is pretty cumbersome and *would like to ask if there's another way to make the code more efficient to do it in 1 loop.*

```
const groupItemByCategories = (arr) => {
  
  blockMenuEl.innerHTML = '';
  const cateArr = arr.map(item => item.categoryLabel);
  cateArr.forEach(cate => {
    const filteredArr = arr.filter(arr => arr.categoryLabel === cate);
    displayAccordingToCategories(filteredArr, cate);
  }) 
}
```

In the code above, I am first getting all the `categoryLabel` and then iterate through the original array (blocks) below, and call a function to display all the items on to the page.

This is the array that is passed in as the parameter:

```
const blocks = [
  {
    label: 'Burger',
    categoryId: 'burgers',
    categoryLabel: 'Burgers',
    tags: [ 'burger', 'lettuce', 'tomato' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Cheese Burger',
    categoryId: 'burgers',
    categoryLabel: 'Burgers',
    tags: [ 'cheese', 'burger', 'lettuce', 'tomato' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Veggie Burger',
    categoryId: 'burgers',
    categoryLabel: 'Burgers',
    tags: [ 'vegetable', 'burger', 'lettuce', 'tomato' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Fancy Burger',
    categoryId: 'burgers',
    categoryLabel: 'Burgers',
    tags: [ 'cheese', 'burger', 'lettuce', 'tomato', 'fancy sauce' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Cheese Fries',
    categoryId: 'fries',
    categoryLabel: 'Fries',
    tags: [ 'fries', 'cheese', 'potato', 'fried' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Shake',
    categoryId: 'dessert',
    categoryLabel: 'Dessert',
    tags: [ 'shake', 'milk', 'chocolate', 'strawberry', 'frozen', 'dessert', 'sweet' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Tots',
    categoryId: 'fries',
    categoryLabel: 'Fries',
    tags: [ 'fries', 'potato', 'fried', 'tater' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Kombucha',
    categoryId: 'drinks',
    categoryLabel: 'Drinks',
    tags: [ 'fermented', 'draft' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Hot Dog',
    categoryId: 'dog',
    categoryLabel: 'Hot Dogs',
    tags: [ 'relish', 'onion', 'cheese sauce', 'chopped bacon' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Fries',
    categoryId: 'fries',
    categoryLabel: 'Fries',
    tags: [ 'fries', 'cheese', 'potato', 'fried' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Tee Shirt',
    categoryId: 'merchandise',
    categoryLabel: 'Merchandise',
    tags: [ 'apparel' ]
  }
];
```

The rest of the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="block-selector">
  <div class="search">
    <input id="search" placeholder="Search Content Blocks" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
  <div id="block-menu"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, input {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}


.block-selector {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 40px;
/*   height: 500px; */
  width: 400px;
  background: #fcfcfc;
/*   border: 1px solid #E8E8E8; */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.block-selector .search {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
}

.block-selector .search input {
  padding: 11px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  line-height: 28px;
  width: 100%;
}

.block-selector .search input::placeholder {
  color: silver;
}

.block-selector .icon {
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
}

#block-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.categoryName {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.allItems {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
/*   justify-content: flex-start; */
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

JS:

```
/*
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fUBeQtBFC962aIztTb5TvvnetmRNL2J0IJ9ToSdmrvs/edit#heading=h.b98xc82r9k1v


*/

const blocks = [
  {
    label: 'Burger',
    categoryId: 'burgers',
    categoryLabel: 'Burgers',
    tags: [ 'burger', 'lettuce', 'tomato' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Cheese Burger',
    categoryId: 'burgers',
    categoryLabel: 'Burgers',
    tags: [ 'cheese', 'burger', 'lettuce', 'tomato' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Veggie Burger',
    categoryId: 'burgers',
    categoryLabel: 'Burgers',
    tags: [ 'vegetable', 'burger', 'lettuce', 'tomato' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Fancy Burger',
    categoryId: 'burgers',
    categoryLabel: 'Burgers',
    tags: [ 'cheese', 'burger', 'lettuce', 'tomato', 'fancy sauce' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Cheese Fries',
    categoryId: 'fries',
    categoryLabel: 'Fries',
    tags: [ 'fries', 'cheese', 'potato', 'fried' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Shake',
    categoryId: 'dessert',
    categoryLabel: 'Dessert',
    tags: [ 'shake', 'milk', 'chocolate', 'strawberry', 'frozen', 'dessert', 'sweet' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Tots',
    categoryId: 'fries',
    categoryLabel: 'Fries',
    tags: [ 'fries', 'potato', 'fried', 'tater' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Kombucha',
    categoryId: 'drinks',
    categoryLabel: 'Drinks',
    tags: [ 'fermented', 'draft' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Hot Dog',
    categoryId: 'dog',
    categoryLabel: 'Hot Dogs',
    tags: [ 'relish', 'onion', 'cheese sauce', 'chopped bacon' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Fries',
    categoryId: 'fries',
    categoryLabel: 'Fries',
    tags: [ 'fries', 'cheese', 'potato', 'fried' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Tee Shirt',
    categoryId: 'merchandise',
    categoryLabel: 'Merchandise',
    tags: [ 'apparel' ]
  }
];

const PLACEHOLDER_SRC = 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/design-n-code/100/272127c4-8d19-4bd3-bd22-2b75ce94ccb4-512.png';

const blockMenuEl = document.getElementById('block-menu');

const renderBlock = (block) => {
  const { label } = block;
  const blockEl = document.createElement('div');
  const iconEl = document.createElement('img');
  const textEl = document.createElement('p');

  blockEl.classList.add('block');
  textEl.innerText = label;
  iconEl.classList.add('icon');
  iconEl.setAttribute('src', PLACEHOLDER_SRC);

  blockEl.appendChild(iconEl);
  blockEl.appendChild(textEl);
  return blockEl;
};

blocks.forEach((block) => blockMenuEl.appendChild(renderBlock(block)));

/*
grouping:
When getting all the categories, create a block. Add style to that block

*/
const grouping = (blockMenuEl) => {
  // get the categoryLabel
  const results = groupItemByCategories(blocks);
  
  // display them
  // displayAccordingToCategories(results);
  return results;
}

/*
get all the items according to 1 category
call the display function:
+) blockMenuEl.innerHTML = ''
+) take the category
+) create a new div for each item
+) blockMenuEl.appendChild(eachblock)

*/
const groupItemByCategories = (arr) => {
  // get all the items name
  
  /*
  I could do the below by doing .map to get all the categoryLabel name
  Then chain map and filter  
  */
  blockMenuEl.innerHTML = '';
  const cateArr = arr.map(item => item.categoryLabel);
  cateArr.forEach(cate => {
    const filteredArr = arr.filter(arr => arr.categoryLabel === cate);
    displayAccordingToCategories(filteredArr, cate);
  }) 
}


const displayAccordingToCategories = (filteredArr, cate) => {
  const categoryDiv = document.createElement('div');
  categoryDiv.textContent = cate;
  categoryDiv.classList.add('categoryName');
  
  const allItems = document.createElement('div');
  allItems.classList.add('allItems');
  filteredArr.forEach(item => {
    const itemDiv = renderBlock(item);
    allItems.appendChild(itemDiv);
  })
  
  // categoryDiv.appendChild(allItems);
  blockMenuEl.appendChild(categoryDiv);
  blockMenuEl.appendChild(allItems);
}

grouping(blockMenuEl);

/*
search function

*/
const originalHTML = blockMenuEl.innerHTML;

const searchEle = (e) => {
  // filter
  const received = e.target.value;
  const key = received.toLowerCase();
  const filteredResults = filterEle(key);
  
  // put res on the page
  display(filteredResults);
}

const filterEle = (key) => {
  const store = blocks.filter(block => {
    const newLabel = block.label.toLowerCase();
    const newCatLabel = block.categoryLabel.toLowerCase();
    return newLabel.includes(key) || newCatLabel.includes(key) || block.tags.some(tag => tag.includes(key));
  })
  return store;
}

const display = (arr) => {
  // this works but why
  // can't do arr.length = 0 because filteredResults will never be 0
  if(arr.length === blocks.length) {
    blockMenuEl.innerHTML = originalHTML;
  }else {
    // why does this work
    // because it clears the html so I can attach something on to it
    blockMenuEl.innerHTML = '';
    return arr.forEach(res => {
      const result = renderBlock(res);
      blockMenuEl.appendChild(result);
    })
  }
}


const search = document.querySelector('#search');
// figure out how to use arrow function here
search.addEventListener('keyup', searchEle);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using 3 loops: `.map`, `.forEach`, `.filter`

First kind of approximation (2 loops):

```js
const groupItemByCategories = (arr) => {
  blockMenuEl.innerHTML = '';
  let categ = {};

  for (let x of arr) {
    if (!(x.categoryLabel in categ)) { categ[x.categoryLabel] = [] }
    categ[x.categoryLabel].push(x)
  }

  for (let c in categ) {
    displayAccordingToCategories(categ[c], c);
  }
}
```

Note also that objects accesses are faster then array accesses.

Comment: Doesn't your solution also use 3 loops?

Comment: You mean the `in` keyword? Yes it is implemented with a loop, but is much way shorter and faster than checking it with a filter on the full array: complexity `O(n_categories)` vs `O(n_array)`, and also is computationally faster to access objects vs arrays